# Sendmessage to Total Commander using C#

Tags: c#, autoit, sendmessage

I am trying to convert some of my codes from Autoit to C#. In Autoit I can send a message to Total Commander using the following code:

```
$hWnd = WinGetHandle("[Active]")
DllCall("user32.dll", "int", "SendMessage", "hwnd", $hWnd, "int", 1075, "int", 2027, "int", 0)
```

This will send the command 2018 to total commander. This command is for printing a directory content. Now I'd like to translate this to C#. My code now looks like this:

```
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
public static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int uMsg, int wParam, string lParam);    

SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), 0x1075, 2027, "");
```

However this code doesn't work!

From Total Commander forum:
**1075 is the message identifier. From TC point of view, 1075 is the message used to send commands to TC (http://ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=75654#75654)**

Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're sure you're getting the right window handle with `GetForegroundWindow()`, the other issue is that you're passing 1075 as a hex value.  [This post](http://www.ghisler.ch/board/viewtopic.php?p=54834&sid=240218c9f23c6595f068c0d564237c69#54834) indicates that the magic 1075 number is actually `WM_USER` + 51.

[`WM_USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644931(v=vs.85).aspx) is 0x400, and in decimal that is 1024.  Add 51 decimal and you get 1075.
So you probably want:

```
SendMessage(GetForegroundWindow(), 1075, 2027, "");
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. 1075 does not work, but I tried 0x400+51 and it works :) thank you

Comment: No worries!  I'm very surprised at the 0x400+51 working where 1075 does not; (0x400 + 51) results in decimal 1075.  Perhaps there was something else going on?

Comment: You are right! I tried again and 1075 also works! I must have entered 1024 by mistake. Thanks again!